# Sorcery vs witchcraft

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, dr-strange-multiverse-of-madness, magic

In *Doctor Strange in the Multiverse of Madness*, when speculating over the origin and nature of the demon that attacked them and tried to abduct the girl, after noticing the runes (symbols) on the creature's skin, Strange says

> *"**that's not sorcery, that's witchcraft**"*.

This seems to imply there's a distinct and substantial difference between sorcery and witchcraft. I am just wondering what that difference is?

Comment: Murky at best, and poorly defined; https://screenrant.com/mcu-magic-sorcerery-witchcraft-differences-most-powerful/

Comment: Some useful stuff here. Some nonsense about dimensional energies and whatnot. Probably someone can bash this into an answer for you; https://marvelcinematicuniverse.fandom.com/wiki/Magic#Chaos_Magic:~:text=English-,Magic,-SIGN%20IN%20TO